# How do I force Django to save decimals to a float database column

Tags: django, python-2.6

I'm trying to make my own field for some money calculations in a single currency, and I am unable to use a decimal datatype in my database, this is what i have so far. I'm really only just learning about custom field types and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
class MoneyField(models.DecimalField):
    """
    """

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, seperator=',', dp='.', pos='', neg='-', trailneg='', **kwargs):
        models.DecimalField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, **kwargs)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return models.DecimalField.__name__

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        value = getattr(model_instance, self.attname)
        if self.decimal_places > 0:
            dp_modifier = Decimal(1 / Decimal(pow(10, self.decimal_places)))
        else:
            dp_modifier = Decimal(1)
        if value != None:
            value = Decimal(str(value))

        print value
        print type(value.quantize(Decimal(dp_modifier)))
        return value.quantize(Decimal(dp_modifier))

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            if self.decimal_places > 0:
                dp_modifier = Decimal(1 / Decimal(pow(10, self.decimal_places)))
            else:
                dp_modifier = Decimal(1)
            if value != None:
                value = Decimal(str(value))
            return super(MoneyField, self).to_python(value).quantize(Decimal(dp_modifier))
        except AttributeError:
            return None

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        return float(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return float(value)
```

Exception:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/appdata/joinery/costing/cost-boughtin-by-item/glass/1A346B0F-0705-11E2-9E84-7071BCB8D2AB/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'appdata.generic',
 'appdata.contacts',
 'appdata.dashboard',
 'appdata.scheduler',
 'appdata.financial',
 'appdata.work',
 'appdata.boughtin',
 'appdata.bespoke',
 'appdata.joinery',
 'appdata.home',
 'appdata.globaltags',
 'appdata.importdata',
 'appdata.database',
 'appdata.ads',
 'appdata.workshop',
 'appdata.transfer',
 'appdata.setup',
 'appdata.languages',
 'appdata.machine_output',
 'appdata.machine_output.modules',
 'appdata.printing',
 'django_cpserver',
 'appdata.djangologdb',
 'raven.contrib.django']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'appdata.middleware.UserAgent',
 'appdata.middleware.SiteLogin',
 'appdata.middleware.RequestIdent',
 'appdata.middleware.ProfilerMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
 'djangologdb.middleware.LoggingMiddleware',
 'raven.contrib.django.middleware.Sentry404CatchMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\appdata\joinery\costing.py" in cost_boughtin
  202.         net_cost, charge_out, xml = calc_model.objects.cost_by_item(item,get_xml=True)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\appdata\joinery\models.py" in cost_by_item
  719.         return self._cost_component_list(item_list, costbook, get_xml, item=item)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\appdata\joinery\models.py" in _cost_component_list
  699.             calc_data = self._cost_components(calc_item_list, costbook)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\appdata\joinery\models.py" in _cost_components
  688.             calc_item.apply_cost(cost_item, item_cache)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\appdata\joinery\models.py" in apply_cost
  1024.         calc_component.save()
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  526.                         rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _update
  491.         return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  869.         cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  725.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  834.                 val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\subclassing.py" in inner
  28.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  786.         return connection.ops.value_to_db_decimal(self.to_python(value),
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  761.             return decimal.Decimal(value)
File "C:\JoinerySoft\Development\working folder\lib\decimal.py" in __new__
  653.                             "First convert the float to a string")

Exception Type: TypeError at /appdata/joinery/costing/cost-boughtin-by-item/glass/1A346B0F-0705-11E2-9E84-7071BCB8D2AB/
Exception Value: Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string
```

Comment: I want to know how to force django to save like a floatfield. at the moment it's attempting to save like a decimal field, and it just won't work

Comment: Do you get exceptions? What happens?

Comment: @miki725 i do, have posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be approaching the problem from wrong direction. Instead of trying to save Decimal field in db as float, you should be trying to get Decimal values from float field.

Try something in this nature:

```
class MoneyField(models.FloatField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        t_value = type(value)

        if t_value is Decimal:
            return value

        elif t_value is float:
            return Decimal.from_float(value)

        elif t_value in (str, unicode,):
            return Decimal(value)

        else:
            raise TypeError('Unsupported value type: %s' % str(t_value))

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return float(value)
```

So what this does is it works same as float field hence is compatible with float fields in db. However whenever the value is retrieved, it makes sure to return a decimal version of the float number. And when trying to save the field, it converts it to float.

Haven't tested so not sure if 100% correct but I think this should get you in the right direction. On top of this, you can enforce all of the money things...

Comment: python 2.6, i don't think you can use from_float